# What are some good resources for getting started with/learning APL?

Tags: apl

I'm trying to get started with APL and any related IDEs, tools, compilers, etc. I may need to install locally. I also looked at the APL repl online, but all the symbols seem to be very tough to type (I don't even know where to get started).

I would like to know of any online resources, software or packages I need to install, as well as books or courses on APL. I don't think there was a good answer on StackOverflow about this question, so I would be very grateful if anyone can point me towards the right direction.

Comment: pretty much all APL I learned was with great support from the folks at the [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) chatroom. I also enjoy the lessons that are held there every other week and that [have been recorded](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52405/the-apl-orchard?tab=conversations) for folks like you and me to learn from them many months later.

Comment: I can second the APL Orchard as a great resource for learning APL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A great portal for APL resources is [APL Wiki](https://aplwiki.com/).

I think [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/download-zone.htm) is the friendliest interpreter for local install.

For an easy to use online REPL, check out [Try APL](https://tryapl.org/) which has a floating keyboard, a click-to-insert "Primer" for the symbols, and also allows using backtick <kbd>`</kbd> as a prefix key to type. APL Wiki has more in-depth information on [typing glyphs](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Typing_glyphs).

APL Wiki is again the place to go to for [learning resources](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Learning_resources).

Finally, the [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) is a very active chat room here on Stack Exchange, where plenty of friendly APLers are ready to help, explain, discuss, and teach. I'll always respond if you ping me with @Adám there ― and when I'm online, often immediately.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer! I'm looking forward to exploring these resources and APL Orchard based on everyone's feedback.